# Using CSS to highlight entire row

Tags: html, css

I am using the below code to highlight a table rows, but it does not highlight the row.

It highlight only the current cell and it only turns the font color to white when i hover over the actual font.

Is there something I am missing?

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.schedule tr:not(:first-child) :hover{
        font-weight:bold;
        cursor:default;
        background-color:#B80D9F;
        color:white;
    }
    
    .schedule{
        border-spacing:0px;
    }
```

```html
 <table class="schedule" width="90%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%">hello1</td>
                <td style="width:50%">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%">hello2</td>
                <td style="width:50%">123</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Update:**

All the answers below are correct, but do not address the second issue with the font not changing to white when a `<a>` tag is used.

Why would the font-color not change?

Comment: anchors default font color is blue. so you have to specify your styles for anchor tags separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space before `:hover`, because actually your try to access to the children of tr, not the `tr` itself

And color is setted with custom style on `a`, you have to add another css selector on `a` to change its color :

```
.schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover a{
   color:white;
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple... Thank you :)

Comment: One last thing... It seems if the text contains a `<a>` it does not change the font color. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as following, you have mistake in your rule :-

```
.schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#B80D9F;
    color:white;
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: It would better help for OP if you explain what mistake he/she did.

Comment: I have already added first line that you have mistake in your rule :)

Comment: I understand that but still if you try to be more specific then it would be good for OP. For ex: answer given by @Arnaud , So that OP can know that exactly where and in which line/rule he did mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

All things updated.Please see working [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/v4w5suyw/1/) and enjoy!!
Spacing problem before `:hover`

HTML:

```
<table class="schedule" width="90%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%">hello1</td>
        <td style="width:50%">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%"><a href="">hello2</a></td>
        <td style="width:50%"><a href="">123</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
 .schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover{
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:default;
  background-color:#B80D9F;
  color:white;
}
 .schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
.schedule tr:not(:first-child) a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 }
.schedule{
 border-spacing:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css to:

```
.schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover{
   font-weight:bold;
   cursor:default;
   background-color:#B80D9F;
   color:white;
}

.schedule{
   border-spacing:0px;
}
```

the issue you had was the space before the `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is with the space

```
.schedule tr:not(:first-child):hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#B80D9F;
    color:white;
}

.schedule{
    border-spacing:0px;
}
```